# Case in Where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write one Stored Procedure, In which I have to find the value from the table on the basis of Last Name, Last name search criteria can be Exact, Begin with or Phonetic. 
SP will be like -

```
SELECT * FROM  Person       
    WHERE (
       CASE @lastNameCriteria 
       WHEN 'EXACT' THEN    Person.LastName = @LastName
       WHEN 'BEGIN' THEN    Person.LastName like @LastName
       ELSE SOUNDEX(tblPerson.LastName) LIKE SOUNDEX(@lastName))
```

I dont know above query will give in SQL. I dont want to use dynamic query, I can not use "IF ELSE", because there might be some other criteria like FirstNameCriteria, MiddleNameCriteria, which will increase the complexity of "IF ELSE".
Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: I edited it to something that will pretty close to work - added one word - END - and deleted the CASE parameter and a left-paren.

Comment: @le dorfier - Please post an answer instead of **fixing** the question. If we fix the question such that it works, the answer will no longer make sense, or even be necessary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CASE statement properly like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Person 
WHERE
    CASE @lastNameCriteria
    WHEN 'EXACT' THEN
        CASE WHEN Person.LastName = @LastName THEN 1 END
    WHEN 'BEGIN' THEN
        CASE WHEN Person.LastName like @LastName THEN 1 END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN SOUNDEX(tblPerson.LastName) = SOUNDEX(@lastName) THEN 1 END
    END = 1
```

Which will **force** SQL Server to evaluate the @lastNameCriteria before processing the embedded conditions.  You can also use multiple OR clauses which by virtue of @lastNameCriteria being compared to a string literal will cause `short-circuit` boolean evaluation - the parts involving the column comparison is not evaluated unless the @lastNameCriteria matches).

```
SELECT *
FROM Person 
WHERE
(@lastNameCriteria = 'EXACT' AND Person.LastName = @LastName)
OR
(@lastNameCriteria = 'BEGIN' AND Person.LastName like @LastName)
OR
(isnull(@lastNameCriteria,'') NOT IN ('EXACT','BEGIN')
 AND SOUNDEX(tblPerson.LastName) = SOUNDEX(@lastName))
--option(recompile)
```

Notes:

1. **Don't** (have to) use **LIKE** between the SOUNDEX, it is a simple `=` that you are after
2. I made no assumptions about `@lastNameCriteria` which is why it is tested for both nulls and not in the other two
3. If you are worried about parameter sniffing or incorrect query plans, uncomment the  `option (recompile)` bit. Planning (each time) for such a simple query should take insignificant time.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Person  WHERE     CASE @lastNameCriteria     WHEN 'EXACT' THEN         CASE WHEN Person.LastName = @LastName THEN 1 END     WHEN 'BEGIN' THEN         CASE WHEN Person.LastName like @LastName THEN 1 END     ELSE         CASE WHEN SOUNDEX(tblPerson.LastName) = SOUNDEX(@lastName) THEN 1 END     END = 1

Comment: @Reena - if you're still having problems either update your question or post a new one.

Comment: Yes, I am still having problem -

Comment: If I add more conditions like "AND (Person.DateOfBirth = coalesce(@dateOfBirth,Person.DateOfBirth,@dateOfBirth))", then Case does not work. Will you please let me know the reason?

Comment: @Reena - you add it AFTER the entire `CASE.. END = 1` part, i.e. `WHERE CASE.. END = 1 AND (Person...`  But you could just use the 2nd query. Make sure you bracket the current conditions otherwise the OR/AND won't work correctly

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it in a sinlge SELECT, you will kill any chance for the optimizer to come up with a reasonable execution plan. Use three distinct SELECTs instead:

```
IF @lastNameCriteria  = 'EXACT' THEN
   SELECT * FROM  Person WHERE Person.LastName = @LastName
ELSE IF @lastNameCriteria   = 'BEGIN' THEN
  SELECT * FROM  Person WHERE Person.LastName like @LastName
ELEE
  SELECT * FROM  Person WHERE SOUNDEX(tblPerson.LastName) LIKE SOUNDEX(@lastName)
```

This way the query optimizer can create the appropriate plan for each case and, at the very least, use an index for the EXACT case.

Comment: +1 sometimes it's hard for programmers to remember that DRY doesn't apply to SQL the same way.

Comment: @Matthew: true. Unfortunately SQL is the kind of verbose language designers favored in the 70s and is completely out of touch with today code reuse aware, DRY conscious and lambda raised developers.

Comment: One can default to DRY to the 95% of the code base where it doesn't make a difference anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the OP's question, you *could* do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  Person       
WHERE 
   (@lastNameCriteria = 'EXACT' and Person.LastName = @LastName) or
   (@lastNameCriteria = 'BEGIN' and Person.LastName like @LastName) or
   (@lastNameCriteria = 'SOUNDEX' and SOUNDEX(tblPerson.LastName) LIKE SOUNDEX(@lastName))
```

Comment: +1 this will also work, as the second conditions will not be considered when parameter matches the literal

Comment: This has made an assumption that @lastNameCriteria will be `'SOUNDEX'` for the 3rd branch which does not match the question.

Comment: @Richard, I think you're being pedantic, because surly it will have *some* value -- so just use that.

Comment: Can it not be null for the most common use case (just needs to sound like)? `Yes I'm being doubly pedantic` but I (most times) state assumptions if I make them, habit

Comment: @Richard, fair enough -- it would have been worth my mentioning the assumption.